# Android: Make phone call from service

Tags: android, phone-call

I try to make a phone call from inside a service. The code I use is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
startActivity(intent);
```

and it works well from inside the main activity, but not from the service. The error occurs on the last line. Is it not possible to make a call inside a service?

And how could I make this piece of code run on the main activity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try as to   make a phone call from inside a service:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I get error: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: `No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL flg=0x10000004 }`

Answer (score -1):

check in the manifest if the service is outside of any activity