# make phone call when specific notification arrive

Tags: java, android, notifications, call

i'm trying to make a phone call, when a specific notification arrive,
i use Notification Service Listener to read incoming notificaion,

```
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    //  if(if this is my notificaion..){
    String name = sbn.getNotification().extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE));
    List<String> numbers = getPhoneNumbers(name);
    Log.d(TAG, "i have all this numbers - " + numbers.toString());

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + numbers.get(1)));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

the "getPhoneNumbers" method is this one

```
public List<String> getPhoneNumbers(String name) {
    List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
            "DISPLAY_NAME = '" + name + "'", null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String contactId =
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        //  Get all phone numbers.
                    Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
           numbers.add(number);

        }
        phones.close();
    }

    cursor.close();
    return numbers;

}
```

all work fine, ( i used break points to cheak everything...)
the "if this is my notification" work perfect, i get the name from the sbn extras, the 'numbers' arraylist include all the contact numbers after the "getPhoneNumbers" method used, but when i start the intent nathing happend..

what is my problem? :/

Answer (score 1):

Let's clarify:

**Problem**
Your `onNotificationPosted` method does not launch a phone call when calling `startActivity(intent);`.

**Why**
`NotificationListenerService` is not an activity.

**Solution** 
Make your `MainActivity` call the `startActivity(intent);`.

**How**
Define an attribute `activity` in `NotificationListenerService` and define a constructor that accepts an activity:

**NotificationListenerService.java**

```
// define attribute activity:
MainActivity activity;

public NotificationListenerService(MainActivity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
// create a NotificationListenerService sending itself as reference
NotificationListenerService nls = new NotificationListenerService(this);
```

Then inside the `onNotificationPosted` you will see the attribute, so you can:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"+ numbers.get(1)));
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i want numbers.get(1).. (there is more then 5 numbers for this contact, so i think thats not the problem...),
and this soulation doesnt work :/

Comment: @Didi78 check my edit, i think problem is you can't see `MainActivity` inside `onNotificationPosted`....

Comment: you say that i need to define myActivity = this; in the onNotificationPosted ? i think that's isnt possible because NotificationListenerService isnt an activity..
or maybe i didnt understand you well? i need to define it in my MainActivity? (i have one..)

Comment: Yes, your main activity must start the phone call intent

Comment: well, 30 mins and i didnt figure out what did you mean too, 
in the main activity i need the -
public Activity getActivity() {
    return this;
}
that's ok, but what next?  the "public Activity myActivity = this" inside NotificationListenerService still doesnt work, and if you say that my main activity must start the phone call intent, so - 
1. why should i write the "Intent intent = new In(..;
myActivity.startActivity(intent) inside the onNotificationPosted (like you wrote..)
2. i dont want any layout to be opened when the notificiation arrive, just start the call..
sorry for my stupidity :/

Comment: @Didi78 sorry for delay, yesterday i got no time. I totally updated my answer to clarify exactly what I meant, also I used a simpler technique, let me now if further doubts...

Comment: thanks but i found a simpller solution to add 'Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND' and then i can make a call from the service itself, according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915086/android-make-phone-call-from-service , thank you very much for all your help!!